# FluentValidation: Customizing the error message with values from other properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have this:

```
 RuleForEach(inputData => inputData.Loads).ChildRules(inputData => {
        inputData.RuleFor(load => load.Asnow).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0).WithMessage("no negative snow allowed"));
.... etc
```

Now I want to express in the message, which of the loads in the Loads collection the message is about.

"load" has a property "LoadName", the value of which i want to include in the message, something like

```
$"{load.LoadName} no negative snow allowed"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WithMessage(Func<T, string>)` overload:

```
RuleForEach(inputData => inputData.Loads)
    .ChildRules(inputData =>
    {
        inputData.RuleFor(load => load.Asnow).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0).WithMessage(load => $"{load.LoadName} no negative snow allowed");
    });
```